# How I can get timers list in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, timer

For example I have .js file, it's a single script. I have some functions In this script and this functions are making some timers (setTimeout). All of this timers wasn't associated with the variables.

Like a

```
function zzz(){
    setTimeout(yyy, 100);
};
```

I need to know when all of this timers will be done, if Node JS has some event for it. Or I need list of all timers in this script, if it exists. To check length of this list in any random moment for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) and emit an event at the end of your `setTimeout` callback. You can then work a solution to track when all of your expected events have fired around this. Extending the example in the docs:

```
'use strict';

const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

myEmitter.on('event', (data) => {
  console.log(data); // yyy
});

function yyy() {
  return;
}

setTimeout(() => {
  yyy();
  myEmitter.emit('event', 'yyy');
}, 100);
```